# Any password is working with SmartAdmin MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, smartadmin

I'm able to authenticate using anything for a password. The email has to be a valid registered email, but the pwd doesn't matter. Everything else is working normally.

Any suggestions on where to start trouble shooting this? I haven't found any similar issues in web searches.

My view...

My action in the account controller...

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountLoginModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(viewModel);

        var user = _manager.FindByEmail(viewModel.Email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, viewModel.RememberMe);

            string uid = user.Id;
            return RedirectToLocal(viewModel.ReturnUrl);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

and the signinasync method...

```
private async Task SignInAsync(IdentityUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        // Clear any lingering authencation data
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // Create a claims based identity for the current user
        var identity = await _manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Write the authentication cookie
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(identity.Name, isPersistent);
    }
```

I did create a seperate MVC web project to see the scaffolded login action, which is quite a bit different. The SmartAdmin template is customized enough that its difficult to start changing things without knowing what I'm effecting. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: You are not comparing the password anywhere in the code. You are just getting user details by email from database and signs in the user if user exists. You need to check the password too if user is found and if password matches then only you should sign in the user.

Comment: what does `SignInAsync` method look like?

Comment: added signinasync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `username` in your system is `email`, you should use

```
var user = _manager.FindAsync(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password);
```

and then signin the user if it's not null.

If `username` is not `email`, you should first get the `user` and then check for password

```
var user = _manager.FindByEmail(viewModel.Email);
bool isPasswordCorrect = await _manager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, viewModel.Password);
```

Comment: The source is in the github